# Android extends Activity -- Button White

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-button, android-actionbaractivity

I made a new Project in Android Studio and MainActivity extends android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity by default.  I did not want to use the support library so I made MainActivity extend android.app.Activity.

This simple change removes the visual effects of clicking and and unclicking a button, i.e. it has a visual for being unclicked and a visual for being down-clicked.

Do I need to re-implement that behavior manually in the onClick method and determine if the button is down/up because the layout XML file never changed so the behavior must be in the ActionBarActivity class, but if you open the class it has /* compiled code */.

OR

Should I just use ActionBarActivity because the min SDK is API 8 Froyo and I didn't want to depend on higher level API features because the app is so simple.

Comment: If you specify NOT to use the support library, it will use the target SDK. What is your target SDK? and what platform are you testing on?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I discovered my ignorance. I didn't look in the AndroidManifest.xml file.  

The android:theme attribute was set to "@style/AppTheme" and I had to set it to "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

Comment: @style/AppTheme is a custom style created by Android Studio when the project is first created and is in res/values/styles.xml.